# Attribute Error when trying to access device ID Alexa

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

I'm currently building an Alexa skill which will eventually need the users Zip Code. I'm going off of this code: https://data-dive.com/alexa-get-device-location-from-custom-skill

The problem I'm having is this line: 
'TOKEN = context.System.user.permissions.consentToken'
and the error: 
'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'consentToken''

I have already requested permissions through the Alexa dev console, but my guess is that there isn't something going right when I'm testing. I tried testing through the Alexa app on my phone but came to the same error. Any steps in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Try to log the request and see whether the consentToken exists. BTW consentToken is now deprecated. Use apiAccessToken if you are in the early stage of development.

Comment: Huge help in pointing out that consentToken is no longer used. However, now I'm running into a problem which gives me the error:  return statement("your zip code is" + location["postalCode"].encode("utf-8"))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I recommend using the test console. See https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#test-simulator The test console show the requests sent from Alexa to you skill's backend.

Comment: Btw. the documentation also states not to use the consentToken any more. Use `context.System.accessToken` instead. https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html#get-the-api-access-token-and-device-id

Answer (score 0):

> `consentToken` is deprecated

Requests from Alexa may also include a `consentToken` within `session.user.permissions` and `context.System.user.permissions`.

Existing skills that use consentToken continue to work, but the `context.System.apiAccessToken` property should be used instead.

For more details you can refer this [link](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html#get-the-api-access-token-and-device-id)